# Car insurance with foreign and domestic Driver's License

Tags: united-states, car, car-insurance

I am currently living in the U.S. I am looking to get a car insurance and wonder how they calculate my rate. As I know it from Germany, they calculate the risk with a formula depending on where I live, how long I have my Driver's License for and how many accidents I had in the past. Are these roughly the same factors as in the U.S.?

Since I have my German DL license for over 10 years now and just recently (2 months) got a U.S. Driver's License, I wonder how the insurance company will calculate my risk/rate? Do they take the age of my German Driver's License into account or do they just calculate the rate based on the age of the U.S. Driver's License?

**Update:**

I am now insured on a car of my friend. They did not charge any extra fee so therefore I suppose that the insurance also took the age of my German DL into account. They also asked for this when we added myself to the insurance of the car as a driver.

Comment: Do you own or lease (or are planning on buying or leasing) a car? Car insurance, as the term is generally understood in the US, means insurance of a specific vehicle against damage of various kinds, and liability coverage of the owner/lessee and/or operators of the vehicles against claims by people injured in accidents etc.

Answer (score 1):

They would only take your age typically.

A major additional input in the USA is your *Credit Score*, which is calculated from your credit history. In a nutshell, it is high=good when you have a long history of managing debt well and paying on time.

Unfortunately, if you do *not* have a credit history in the USA, it will be considered a negative sign, and you will get insurance only very expensive or not at all. Typically, you cannot get a checking account, rent a house, etc., without a credit history.

Comment: I disagree with the checking account because you can definitely open one, even if you don't have a credit score.

Comment: It is a myth that you can't live without credit history.  You can indeed open a checking account and rent a house without a credit history.

Comment: I have to add that I don't think that my credit score matters too much because when I wanted to get a quote on some pages they asked only for basic information which are non credit score related. Although I am aware of the importance of a credit score I don't think that's applicable to car insurances.

Comment: That's good to know, next time I have the problem I will just tell the bank that it is a myth.